# What is the significance of the X11 ssh-agent?

Tags: ssh, pi-3, raspbian-jessie, ubuntu

Yesterday,  I unmasked a bug in Raspberry PI 3 and Ubuntu Mate 16.04 where  the `ssh-agent` clobbers the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` global environment variable which we wrote to `/etc/environment`  using a bash script. The patch I made was to change `use-ssh-agent` to `no-use-ssh-agent` in `/etc/X11/Xsession.options`

What is the significance of X11 `ssh-agent` ?

Comment: It's under-documented, but it's not a bug; it's a consequence of proper security regarding the execution environment of `ssh-agent`:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=711623

Comment: BTW, what you're doing could be considered [a not-so-good practice](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) (that link also explains why this happens; it's not peculiar to ssh-agent). If you really need to permantently add to the *global system* linker path, you should add an entry to the cache (see `man ldconfig` and examples in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d`).  If all you need to do it for is a few particular applications, you should use shell wrappers and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH there. This is a more correct way to go whether or not you need ssh-agent; the same issue can bite you other ways.

Comment: @goldilocks, Thank you for your great comment. Instead of ldconfig and adding a file to /etc/ld.so.conf.d , could I add the following to the end of $HOME/.bashrc:   for line in $( cat /etc/environment) do export line end

Comment: The (less serious) problem with pre/appending stuff to paths in `.bashrc` is it will tend to get run recursively, if an interactive shell is the child of another interactive shell, so, e.g., `PATH=/foo/bar:$PATH` can end up creating paths like `/foo/bar:/foo/bar:/foo/bar:/bin:...`.  Beyond becoming env clutter that doesn't matter very much, but another issue

Comment: ...is that things spawned, e.g., by init services will never source `.bashrc` (see INVOCATION near the top of `man bash`) and very possibly that includes GUI login sessions (just you won't notice it *in a terminal*, because that is within an interactive shell).  Also, if relevant you are relying on all users using `bash` as their default shell, which may not be the case.

Comment: @goldilocks, Thank you for the great comment . Now, I remember seeing recursive LD_LIBRARY_PATH's such as /foo/bar:/foo/bar:/foo/bar:/bin:..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good place to start is manual page for the configuration file you are modifying: [Xsession.options(5)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/Xsession.options.5.html)

It clearly explains what the option `use-ssh-agent` means with appropriate references to all the other unknown terms for you:

> `use-ssh-agent`
>
> If the `ssh-agent(1)` program is available and no agent process appears to be running already, the X session will be invoked by exec'ing ssh-agent with the startup command, instead of the startup command directly.

In short, I would say that this option controls whether a `ssh-agent` is automatically started for you X11 sessions or not.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. May I ask what ssh has to do with X11? Also, why is it called ssh-agent instead of ssh-server?

Comment: You can find what is `ssh-agent` in its manual page. It is certainly not a ssh server (`sshd` is). SSH can do X11 forwarding, but it is not related in this context. In this context, as I explained in the answer, graphical sessions (X11) starts `ssh-agent` so you do not have to start it on your own and do not have to write passphrase for every `ssh` connection using encrypted keys.

Comment: `ssh-agent` is like a management tool for the `ssh` *client*, but if you aren't using it you don't need it (although as per my comment on the Q setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH globally still is not very wise).

Comment: @Jakuje, Thank you for your comment . What is the meaning of "do not have to write passphrase for every ssh connection using encrypted keys."?

Comment: If you use password protected ssh keys, every time you use them you have to enter the password; `ssh-agent` saves you the hassle (see also `ssh-add`).  That may seem to defeat the purpose of the password but not really: If someone manages to steal the key file, it is still password encrypted.

Comment: @goldilocks, I thought X11 was a sophisticated graphical user interface. May I ask why X11 requires encrypted password keys? Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't.  But you may be using them.  A mechanism `ssh-agent` seems to depend on is environment variables (`env | grep SSH` shows some for the process PID and a local socket address).  Those are passed parent to child, and not vice versa or between cousins, etc.  So to use the environment that way a process must be a direct descendant of whatever set it so; since authentication agents are things people commonly want to use with a desktop session, it's started along with the desktop.  You can then use `ssh-add` within it and it applies to the session's agent.

Comment: @goldilocks, Thanks for your answer. May I ask the significant differences ,if any, between Raspberry Pi 3 & Ubuntu Mate 16.04 running on armv71 processor compared to Ubuntu Linux 16.04 running on x86_64 processor?

Comment: That's kind of a big question you should ask separately.   Also, I'm unlikely to be any help with it as I'm not a Ubuntu fan (not because I think there's anything wrong with it but because I prefer other distros).